# ng-click does not work on elements that are dynamically added by directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a directive that initializes a bootstrap popover which will display a calculator. The calculator popover has a calculate button, which has an ng-click, but i cant get the click event to fire.

After some research; I think i need to use the $compile service, but i just cant seem to figure out exactly how to use it in this situation.

```
define [], ()->
 ($filter, $compile) ->
   ddo = 
    require: "ngModel"
    restrict: "A"
    scope: true
    priority: 10
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$q', ($scope, $element, $q)->

     $scope.calculate = ()->
      console.log "calc"

  ]
  link: (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) ->
    elem.wrap("<div class=\"input-group\"></div>")
    pre = $("<span class=\"input-group-addon\" style=\"font-size:0.8em;\">$</i></span>")
    post = $("<div data-toggle=\"popover\" class=\"input-group-addon pop\"><i class=\"      fa fa-github-alt\" style=\"font-size:0.8em;\"></i></div>")
    elem.before(pre)
    if attrs.showCalc == "true"
      elem.after(post)

    $(".pop").popover(
      {
        html: true, 
        title: 'Calculator', 
        content: "Expression:<input ng-model='data.expression' type='text'></input><br>
                  Result:<input ng-model='data.result' type='text'></input>
                  <div ng-click='calculate()' style='margin-top: 5px;' class='btn btn-default btn-calculate'>Calculate</div>
                  <div ng-click='applyValue()' style='margin-top: 5px;' class='btn btn-default btn-apply'>Apply</div>"
        })
```

Comment: Although this can be made to work, it would be considerably easier to use [angular-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) for this purpose. Is there any particular reason you do not want to use it?

Comment: well i am using this directive on input elements that take a currency amount. The main purpose of this directive is to format what is entered into the element, which i use jquery autonumeric to do. I am really trying to bake this calculator functionality into the currency directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source code of `popover`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/popover.js#L47), it seems that if the `content` is an HTML object, then they append it to the DOM and preserve `js-events` even though this behaviour is undocumented. Hence, this should work (at least in theory):

```
$(".pop").popover(
  {
    html: true, 
    title: 'Calculator', 
    content: $compile("Expression:<input ng-model='data.expression' type='text'></input><br>
              Result:<input ng-model='data.result' type='text'></input>
              <div ng-click='calculate()' style='margin-top: 5px;' class='btn btn-default btn-calculate'>Calculate</div>
              <div ng-click='applyValue()' style='margin-top: 5px;' class='btn btn-default btn-apply'>Apply</div>")
             (scope)
    })
```